# Making multiple singlepart features from one multipart feature using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, features, multipart

I am working with ArcGIS Pro 2.8.

I have a multipart feature class with polygon geometry, and when I select a row with **OBJECTID = 28**, I observed that it is targeting so many features in the map.

[image]

Is there a way to split or make individual rows or features that will allow me to select one feature at a time?

So it's like now I have 100 features getting selected with one row, and I want 100 rows.

Answer (score 1):

Found out!

I just used the **Multipart to SinglePart** Geoprocessing tool in ArcGIS Pro, and the issue is resolved.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/multipart-to-singlepart.htm#

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Explode Multipart tool in the Editing Toolbar, but using a geoprocessing tool usually functions better.